# Why are my database navigation buttons not working in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, parameters, dataset

I have a simple form which connects to a access database and displays records, this code shows whats going on, why is the button im trying to code not working? Im guessing its something to do with the variable which i've not decleared correctly?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace MediaPlayer
{
public partial class Media : Form
{

    // Use this connection string if your database has the extension .accdb
    private const String access7ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MediaDatabase.accdb";
    // Use this connection string if your database has the extension .mdb
    private const String access2003ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MediaDatabase.mdb";

    // Data components
    private OleDbConnection myConnection;
    private DataTable myDataTable;
    private OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter;
    private OleDbCommandBuilder myCommandBuilder;

    // Index of the current record
    private int currentRecord = 0;

    private void FillDataTable(String selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            myAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = selectCommand;
            // Fill the datatable with the rows reurned by the select command
            myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in FillDataTable : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayRow(int rowIndex)
    {
        // Check that we can retrieve the given row
        if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
            return; // nothing to display
        if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
            return; // the index is out of range

        // If we get this far then we can retrieve the data
        try
        {
            DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[rowIndex];
            textBox1.Text = row["FilePath"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = row["Subject"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = row["Keywords"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = row["MediaType"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
        }

    }



    public Media()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            String command = "SELECT * FROM Media";
            try
            {
                myConnection = new OleDbConnection(access7ConnectionString);
                myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(access7ConnectionString, myConnection);
                myCommandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(myAdapter);
                myDataTable = new DataTable();
                FillDataTable(command);
                DisplayRow(currentRecord);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }

    int m_rowPosition = 0; 

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if not at the first row, go back one row and show the record.
        if (m_rowPosition !=0)
        {
            m_rowPosition---;
            this.DisplayRow();
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //move to first row of data and show data
        m_rowPosition = 0;
        this.DisplayRow();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you seeing an error?

Comment: No overload for method 'DisplayRow' takes 0 arguments C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MediaPlayer\MediaPlayer\Media.cs 121 13 MediaPlayer

Comment: your method takes a parameter you need to pass which row you want to display.

Comment: Brillaint, how would i go about this?

Comment: you need this.DisplayRow(m_rowPosition);

Comment: it's a lot easier to help if you follow this http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you want to do this when calling DisplayRow method:

```
DisplayRow(m_rowPosition);
```

or you can change your method to this:

```
private void DisplayRow()
{
    // Check that we can retrieve the given row
    if (myDataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        return; // nothing to display
    if (rowIndex >= myDataTable.Rows.Count)
        return; // the index is out of range

    // If we get this far then we can retrieve the data
    try
    {
        DataRow row = myDataTable.Rows[m_rowPosition];//<- here you using index which value is changed on button click
        textBox1.Text = row["FilePath"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = row["Subject"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = row["Title"].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = row["Keywords"].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = row["MediaType"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in DisplayRow : \r\n" + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using the     DisplayRow(m_rowPosition); and it has stopped the errors, now in order to get it to move i need to check what record its on right?

Comment: Sorry its not show much a error, just nothing happens it wont move to the next record? This is what im trying if (m_rowPosition < myDataTable.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                m_rowPosition++;
                DisplayRow(m_rowPosition);
            }

Comment: ok I understood. Change `m_rowPosition = 0;` to `m_rowPosition++;` in button6 click method.

Comment: Brillaint this works and will take the user back to the first row, sorry but last question what would be the correct syntax so it moves to the next row?

Comment: 'code'  if (m_rowPosition < myDataTable.Rows.Count -1)
            {
                m_rowPosition++;
                DisplayRow(m_rowPosition);
            } this is what i am doing to move to the next record and nothing is happening.

Comment: Im guessing I need to use the variable 'currentRecord' but i just dont know how..

Answer (score 0):

This is being discussed in

[why aren't my buttons working in c# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514161/why-arent-my-buttons-working-in-c-sharp-application)